# Memory leak with Spring MongoDB stream?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, spring-mongodb

The code below causes presumably memory leak:

```
public int reregister(ReregisterDTO reregisterDTO) {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(
        mongoTemplate
            .stream(createQuery(reregisterDTO), Shipment.class))
            .forEach(shipment -> this.reregisterShipment(shipment, count)
    );

    return count.get();
}
```

It has fetched 20000 entities from DB but appears that memory is not released. 
With even bigger volume JVM ran out of memory completely.
How do I free up memory and avoid it? could it be that underlying srping-mongodb code holds reference somewhere?

[image: Memory footprint]

**UPDATE & FIX:**

So apparently I mixed up parentheses here, has to be in this order:

```
    StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(
        mongoTemplate.stream(
            createQuery(reregisterDTO),
            Shipment.class
        )
    ).forEach(shipment -> this.reregisterShipment(shipment, count));
```

Credits to Qingfei Yuan's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need create stream by `StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(Iterator<T>)` instead of use `stream` directly.

Please refer to [Java 8 stream support in MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571667/java-8-stream-support-in-mongotemplate)

Comment: Oh my, such a silly mistake, apparently .forEach(shipment -> this.reregisterShipment(shipment, count) has to be after StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator()! Thank you for pointing to that!